# Endomorphisms of elliptic curves, resp formal groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

Let

- $E$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $K$,
- $\mathcal{E}^w$ a fixed Weierstrass model for $E$ over $R := \mathbf{Z}[a_1,\ldots, a_6]$,
- $\mathcal{E}$ the Néron model of $\mathcal{E}$ over the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$,
- $e$ denote both the unit section respectively in $E(K)$, $\mathcal{E}^w(R)$ and in $\mathcal{E}(\mathcal{O})$.

Let $F$ be the formal group $\text{Spf} (\mathscr{O}_{\mathcal{E}^w,e}^{\wedge})$ on the formal neighborhood of the identity $e$ and $F_{\mathcal{O}}$ the formal group $\text{Spf} (\mathscr{O}_{\mathcal{E},e}^{\wedge})$.

$F$ is usually called "the" formal group of $E$.

> This question asks if it's possible for the formal group of $E$ to carry more endomorphisms than $E$.

More precisely:

> **Question 1** - Is the natural map $$\text{End}_K(E)\to\text{End}_{\text{formal gps}/R}(F)$$ a bijection (resp ring isomorphism)? In other words, is it impossible for the formal group of an elliptic curve over a number field to carry extra endomorphisms?
>
> **Question 2** - same as question 1, but for $F_{\mathcal{O}}$.